# Run several cmd command from batch(.bat) file

Tags: python, django, batch-file

Scenario:
I'm developing a project in `Python` and `Django`. Every time I need to activate my virtual environment and then run webserver. What I do is as follows..

> run cmd then enter the following command
>
> C:\Users\azad>e:
>
> E:>cd E:\Development\Python\djangogirls
>
> E:\Development\Python\djangogirls>dgvenv\Scripts\activate

**this command activate my virtual environment and change my working directory(command prompts)**

> (dgvenv) E:\Development\Python\djangogirls>python manage.py runserver

Now I want to create a windows batch(.bat) file so that I can do the above task with one click.

If I could not make a sense please reply me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```bat
@CD /D "E:\Development\Python\djangogirls"
@Call "dgvenv\Scripts\activate.bat"
@python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Yes! Its Worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat file with your text editor. Then type in the commands you need.
See below code as an example:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\azad
cd E:\Development\Python\djangogirls
dgvenv\Scripts\activate
@py.exe
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: could u pls write the batch file which will exetue the following 4 lines of command one by one
C:\Users\azad>e:
E:>cd E:\Development\Python\djangogirls
E:\Development\Python\djangogirls>dgvenv\Scripts\activate
(dgvenv) E:\Development\Python\djangogirls>python manage.py runserver

Comment: I'm not sure what the second one is. What command is it? Can you paste it on its own?

Comment: I will write the batch file once you read my question and comply.

Comment: @jtrenka 
C:\Users\azad>e: --this line changing direcoty/drive
E:>cd E:\Development\Python\djangogirls --this line changing path to my project folder
E:\Development\Python\djangogirls>dgvenv\Scripts\activate --this linve activate my project virtual environment.
(dgvenv) E:\Development\Python\djangogirls>python manage.py runserver -- this line run my webserver. in this line (dgvenv)
shows automaitcaly when i activate my virtual environment which means my virtual environment is activated.

Comment: Check the edited post.

Unless you can paste the commands - line by line - YOU run every time, it's hard to identify what command it is as I'm not in a Windows environment.